# In Money Heist Part 2 - Episode 9, why does Nairobi say she hates Berlin?

Tags: plot-explanation, money-heist

While trying to pull out the escape in *Money Heist* S02E09 Nairobi reminds Berlin that they were all supposed to go together. Berlin then replies, someone has to hold the fort, and that he was the Misogynist and that Women and Queers are first.

I don't understand. Is he yelling at Helsinki and Nairobi to ESCAPE? Isn't that ideal for Nairobi because she could survive? Why does she hate Berlin for letting her escape first? Like literally an episode ago and almost throughout the series she hated Berlin for treating women very poorly? Or is Berlin NOT allowing Nairobi and Helsinki to escape first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Nairobi loves Berlin very much. She says it to Berlin for letting himself die. She doesn't want him to die.